# Incorrect Looping and returning of variable

Tags: python

My code below is checking if the input (quantity) is a number. If it is a number first time, it returns the number fine. However, if you were to put a letter in, and then when the function loops enter a number, '0' is returned rather than the number you inputted.

```
def quantityFunction():
    valid = False
    while True:
            quantity = input("Please enter the amount of this item you would like to purchase: ")
            for i in quantity:
                try:
                    int(i)
                    return int(quantity)
                except ValueError:
                    print("We didn't recognise that number. Please try again.")
                    quantityFunction()
                    return False
```

Am I looping the function incorrectly?

Comment: You might also want to read this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/23294659/471899

Comment: You must return the value of function, ie. `return quantityFunction()` but still the correct method is the one posted by @Alik.

Comment: Shouldnt it be: `for i in range(quantity):` if quantity is actually a number?

Comment: do you want to stop your loop if a number is entered or you just want to go on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You function is not correct actually, you are using `while` loop together with a `recursion function`, which is not necessary in this case.

While, You could try the following code, which is a bit modification based on your function but use only `while` loop.

```
def quantityFunction():
    valid = False
    while not valid:
        quantity = input("Please enter the amount of this item you would like to purchase: ")
        for i in quantity:
            try:
                int(i)
                return int(quantity)
            except ValueError:
                print("We didn't recognise that number. Please try again.")
                valid = False
                break
```

---

Though, actually you could have done this in a easier way, if you wish to use `while loop`:

```
def quantityFunction():
    while True:
        quantity = input("Please enter the amount of this item you would like to purchase: ")
        if quantity.isdigit():
            return int(quantity)
        else:
            print("We didn't recognise that number. Please try again.")
```

And if you really want to use `recursive function`, try following:

```
def quantityFunction1():
    quantity = input("Please enter the amount of this item you would like to purchase: ")
    if quantity.isdigit():
        return int(quantity)
    else:
        print("We didn't recognise that number. Please try again.")
        return quantityFunction()
```

**Please note** if you want the value to be returned eventually when you type in a number, you need to use `return quantityFunction()` in the `else`. Otherwise eventually nothing will be returned. This also explains your question of why you input a number at the first time you could return it but not afterwards.

Comment: @NathanShoesmith, I updated the answer, this should be another way to achieve what you want.

Comment: @NathanShoesmith, I added the `recursion` function which I think might explain your question that when you input a number at the first time you could return it but not afterwards.